# How to transfer SOL to fixed account from user account?

Tags: anchor

I try to develop SmartContract using Anchor like this

- When user send SOL to me(my public key), My SmartContract will change some data(It's not important)

I would like to HardCoding my public key

```
let server_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str("...............My pub key.....................").unwrap();

let ix = spl_token::instruction::transfer(
    &spl_token::ID,
    ctx.accounts.from.key,
    &server_pubkey,
    ctx.accounts.from.key,
    &[ctx.accounts.from.key],
    10_000_000,
)?;
invoke(&ix, &[
    ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
])?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still have to include the your pubkey in the account context (ctx) of the instruction

You can hardcode your pubkey, and then check it against a constraint

```
const YOUR_PUBKEY: &str = "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr";

#[program]
pub mod test {
...
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InstructionAccounts<'info> {
   ...
   #[account(
        address = YOUR_PUBKEY.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap(),
   )]
   pub server_pubkey: AccountInfo<'info>
}


...
```